# Profiling web worker function calls with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, profiling, web-worker

I'm trying to profile a web worker in Chrome to track down some performance issues, but whereas I get a very complete call tree when profiling the large application, the one I get in the worker thread is almost completely empty:

[image: Profiling with an almost empty call tree]

Is there anything I should observe when profiling web workers in Chrome, or any option I should enable to get the complete list of calls here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the reason was that the web worker was terminated before I stopped profiling. If I keep the worker alive after it finishes its task instead of killing its thread, the profiler works as expected. :)